# CSS/jQuery - Position image label ( p tag ) in the bottom middle of the image

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

I am enclosing image name in p tag, and append it to each image. Currently the p tag will be position at the bottom left of the image, and I not sure how to align it to the middle, either by using jquery or css.

Here is my html construct:

```
<div id="Medium2" style="position: absolute; top: 393px; left: 657px;">
     <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 252px; height: 111px; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px;">
     <img id="Medium2_1" style="width: 252px; height: 111px; resize: none; position: static; display: block;" src="../../Content/ContainerImg/Medium2.png">
     </div>
<p id="165" class="labels" oldtitle="Double click to rename...">IMAGE NAME</p>
```

Any idea how can put the p tag to the middle of the img??

Appreciate any help... thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap both the `<img>` and the `<p>` in the same `<div>` element, and set that `<div>` element's `text-align` property to `center`. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhrTM/

Comment: The HTML you posted in your question does not have the `<p>` inside the same element as the `<img>` (`#Medium2`). They must both have the same parent element for my solution to work. Perhaps you can post your code on jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi, thanks, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/smFhu/7/
But the problem is, I could not wrap the img and the p tag in the same div, because the 2nd div wrapping the image is auto generate by jquery ui ( div class="ui-wrapper" ) since my images r draggables. Any idea i can do this without changing the html construct?? thanks a lot...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/smFhu/10/  I'm using jQuery to get the width of the image and then setting the width of the `p` to be the same as the width of the image. That causes the text to be centered like you want. jsFiddle currently is having trouble connecting to the jQuery source file, but once they fix that you should see it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Medium2" style="position: absolute; top: 393px; left: 657px;">
     <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 252px; height: 111px; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px;">
     <img id="Medium2_1" style="width: 252px; height: 111px; resize: none; position: static; display: block;" src="http://img.track-ip.com/s.php?u=translate.google.com">
     </div>
<p style="text-align:center" id="165" class="labels" oldtitle="Double click to rename...">IMAGE NAME</p>
```

just add `text-align:center` This way it's going to be bottom middle. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I already style the p tag with text-align:center, it dint work...

Comment: Mozilla FF, i think is other styling affecting it.. I updated my style inside, and it dint work already.. http://jsfiddle.net/smFhu/7/

Any idea?? Thanks a lot..

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/smFhu/8/ it still needs a cleanup. do not mix inline styles with CSS. always try to use separate CSS file for semantics and consistency.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. But actually my image is wrapped by the ui-wrapper ( images are draggable ) so i could not remove the div wrapping the image or put the p tag in it. any other idea i can use?? really thanks...